# Confusing for loop C#

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am using this loop to go through my database, and check if players Club field matches the clubAway variable. At if statement it "goes berzerk".

Baza = dataset

Players = table in database

Club = int field

int clubAway

I've checked the values with messagebox, and it says for example: Club = 1 and IDclub = 2.. But it enters the if statement anyway. I have exactly the same for loop, with difference that clubAway is clubHome and it works fine.

```
for (int o = 0; o <= 10; o++)
{
    for (int p = 1; p <= Baza.Players.Count; p++)
    {
        if (Baza.Players[p - 1 + o].Club == clubAway.IDclub)
        {//do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "goes bezerk" isn't a good description for what happens. Please see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. I'd expect an exception, given that `p - 1 + o` can certainly be out of the range of `Baza.Players`.

Comment: do you have something like `Baza.Players[p++]` or something with `o++` in the watch window as these will change the values when stepping through code.

Comment: @JonSkeet he kind of explains what happens- it ignores the if condition and enters the body of the if statement anyway.

Comment: You might add some more context, but from what I see it looks like you have a single array - why are you looping twice?

Comment: What is the purpose of your `o` variable?  A little clarification there, and I can probably help you.

Comment: Document whether you run this code on a machine with a 64-bit operating system and show any try/catch statements in the real code.

Comment: @Seph: No, can't find the problem there.

Comment: @arootbeer: I want to run the inner for loop exactly 11 times. And I want to reach the first player whose 'Club' field equals 'clubAway' value. After that I know that 24 more records have the same value (but I need only first 11 records), so I use 'Baza.Players[p-1+o]'. First time it reaches a correct player. But than it reaches player-1 and it goes through the If statement as true

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: I explaind it in my comment to arootbeer.

Answer (score 4):

I am not clear on the purpose of `o`, but maybe this code will set you on a *better* path:

```
var players = Baza.Players.Where(player => player.Club == clubAway.IDclub).Take(11);

    foreach(var p in players){
        //do something with p
    }
```

## UPDATE

In reading the comments below the original post, I deduce that you are simply trying to find the *first* instance in the set that matches the `clubAway` value.  If that is correct, then one of these code snippets would be more appropriate (depending on your business rules):

```
var player = Baza.Players.FirstOrDefault(player => player.Club == clubAway.IDclub);
```

**OR**

```
var players = Baza.Players;
foreach(var _player in players){
     var player = _player.FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Club == clubAway.IDclub);
     //Now do something with player.
}
```

This will return the "player" entity.  To use it you would do this (for example):

`var playerTeamName = player.teamName;`

Of course, I have no knowledge of your *actual* model, so your code will look different but will follow that pattern.

Good luck!

Comment: As far as I can see it the `o` is for simulating a LINQ `Take(11)` after the `Where`.

Comment: Hmm. It did the same thing. I put the foreach loop into for loop that runs 11 times. (Thanks for the post, I learned that trick now)

Comment: DinoVelić--I think that @Tobias has a point, you seem to be simulating something that is possible with a single LINQ query and subsequent loop.  I am going to edit the code to reflect this and it may help you further, depending on your business rules.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that yo are accessing an illegal element in the collection.  The last valid index into `Baza.Players` is `Baza.Players.Count - 1` yet you are using `p - 1 + o`.  In this case `p` can equal `Baza.Players.Count` and `o` can be `10`.

You need to change the guard condition on the `for` loop.

```
for (int p = 1; p - 1 + o < Baza.Players.Count; p++)
```

Comment: This is clearly a bug, but it doesn't explain why his debugger is entering the `if` block despite an apparent violation of that `if`'s condition.

Comment: @ChrisShain I believe the OP is looking at the wrong index and I'm hoping this will shed light on that.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your code is not compiling correctly, and you are running the 'last good version'.  From the Build menu, select "Clean", then try again.

I am guessing that the source code for the binary that the debugger is connecting to is not the same code that you are seeing in your IDE.  This can happen if you select "Run last good version" when you start debugging, or if you attach to an already running process launched from a location other than your build output folder.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong in the logic of your loop.

Let's say that initially o = 0 and p = 1 (first iteration of the first loop and first iteration of the second loop), then `p-1+o` equals 0, then o = 0 and p = 2 (first iteration of the first loop and second of the second loop) and `p-1+o` equals 1. However later when o = 1 (second iteration of the first loop) and p = 1 (first iteration of the second loop), then `p-1+o` again equals 1, so you're performing a task on the same item really (`Baza.Players[1]` for no apparent reason).

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But I use the same loop just a line before this one, and it does the thing that I want (fills the int array with 1-11 numbers. And this loop gives me an int array with all the numbers 23)